# conectact.html page not showing it show like 404 error i made changes in url still got the same error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

[image][image][image][image]

i am resently create an website using django but this error keep stuck for an week i do all the relaiable changes . I still getting the errore i want contact.html page to be visible like second page click on url i make various changes but still now i can't overcome the error.

Comment: Pls don't post images of code. Pls read: [Why shouldn't I post images of code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the above configurations in place, accessing "http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/" in your web browser should now render the "contact.html" template.